# How to match responses to requests in Netty client?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I'm implementing a http client app with Netty. The task is to send the same request to several endpoints and collect the answers for further processing. Many such requests can be sent concurrently to the same endpoints. The problem is to match responses received from one endpoint to requests.

One possible solution is to create a new handler (and pipeline) for each request as describe here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7905761/4926576. In this case request can be mapped to handler and handler can store the response. But this means creating new connection for each request which will degrade the performance.

I also don't want to change the protocol and include request ids in requests/responses only for the purpose of matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the client and server are respecting HTTP pipelining semantics, then the server must respond to requests in order. Therefore, for each connection, you can maintain a queue of requests. Each new request goes on the back of the queue and each response pops it's matching request from the front of the queue.

In the event of connection failure the queue also provides you with the list of requests that were sent but for which you have not received a response. You can then take appropriate error correcting action for each request.